# R: complete() vs. complete_() when specifying columns as a character vector

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to set up some R code that calls `complete()` with a dynamic list of columns to be "completed".  I'm using a character vector to specify the columns, but `complete()` is erroring out (although the deprecated `complete_()` works just fine).  Any help on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

This code works, but gives a deprecation warning on `complete_()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- tribble(
  ~id, ~val1, ~val2,
  1,   10,    11,
  2,   20,    22
)

key_vars <- colnames(a)[1:length(a)-1]  # Trivialized example of dynamic column selection logic

a %>% complete_(key_vars)
```

> Warning message:
> `complete_()` is deprecated as of tidyr 1.0.0.
> Please use `complete()` instead.

So I try replacing `complete_` with `complete`, but it errors out:

```
a %>% complete(key_vars)
```

> Error: Join columns must be present in data.
> x Problem with `key_vars`.

Should I be using a different syntax to pass the character vector to `complete()`, or is there some other issue?

Comment: The syntax on `complete()` now just takes unquoted column names. Most other `tidyverse` functions are capable of `tidyselect` using either unquoted or quoited column names. It might be best to submit a bug report: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected `a %>% complete(all_of(key_vars))` to work, but it does not. You can do `a %>% complete(!!!rlang::syms(key_vars))`

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks, that works.

Comment: @BenNorris, thanks, I submitted the issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1032#issue-688357446